# combining syntax highlighting in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, python, xml, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to highlight two (or more) languages simultaneously in notepad++?

In this particular case I am working with xml files, but in certain tags in the files I am using using python, JS, and CSS. Now the last two don't bother me too much but there can be large chunks of python code enclosed by `<exec></exec>` tags.
(I saw other questions which ask about JS and html with the same file, but it seems that case is done automatically)

So is it possible to make the program mark up everything inside such tags with the python highlighting it already has?

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ does not offer this functionality as far as I know, but [phpDesigner](https://www.sublimetext.com/) will definitely do it. I used it once for this same reason.

I have also heard that [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) will do it, but I have not tried myself.